# Azure AD B2C as claims provider or Identity provider to Azure AD

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, powerbi-embedded

We are working on application where users will get authenticated with AD B2C. Then that user need to access to other services like Embedded power BI etc which supports only Azure AD, but not B2C.

What options are available to make the authenticated B2C user to access Embedded Power BI reports?

1. Can we make B2C as Identity Provider to Azure AD tenant? If so, any example available?
2. Can we use SSO between B2C and Azure AD?

Answer (score 0):

> Can we make B2C as Identity Provider to Azure AD tenant? If so, any
>   example available?

Azure B2C tenant is developed based on Normal Azure AD and is just for using Azure AD B2C feature. Azure AD B2C feature(not tenant) is just a resource like VM in the normal Azure AD and this feature needs you to switch to B2C tenant to use. Besides, [Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-overview) is an identity management service that enables you to customize and control how customers sign up, sign in, and manage their profiles when using your applications, so you could not make B2C as an identity provider to Azure AD tenant.

> Can we use SSO between B2C and Azure AD?

You can use SSO with Azure AD. For the details, you could refer to [configure single sing-on with Azure AD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/configure-single-sign-on-portal).